# Github git push origin main is not working

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tried everything like ssh agent without and with eval, ssh add and nothing is working.

ssh -Tv git@github.com:

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_rsa type -1     
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1     
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1        
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1   
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1     
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1        
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1   
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1     
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1      
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-322814ef
debug1: no match: babeld-322814ef
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/amita/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk       
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ed25519        
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk     
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_rsa       
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_dsa       
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ecdsa     
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk  
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ed25519   
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/amita/.ssh/id_xmss      
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
```

Comment: May you share what `ssh -Tv git@github.com` outputs?

Comment: it outputs something very long that is longer than i can publish here... @evolutionxbox

Comment: 50 lines of output is too much to put in a question? Don't put it in a comment

Comment: we need `debug1: Will attempt key: ...` to check if your keys are read

Comment: @evolutionxbox added

Comment: Have you stored your private key into `Users/amita/.ssh/` ?

Comment: I really don't know... what's the command to store the private key and ill search.
All I did was follow the instructions https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line
and then in the last thing (the push) I failed with this problem so I did the same with ssh instead of URL and than another problem and I wrote the whole ssh thing that I found on google(i don't know what that means I just find it as a solution to my problem and it didn't work either
@Ôrel

Comment: you need to generate your private and public key. Add your *public* key on github

Comment: Read more about that here https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: tnx guys, it all worked, 
but now i can use this ssh key to push all of my projects?

Answer (score 1):

> it all worked, but now i can use this ssh key to push all of my projects?

Try by testing that new URL on one of your project:

```
cd /path/to/project1
git remote -v
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<me>/<project1>
```

(Replace `<me>/<project1>` by the values seen when typing git remote -v)

Test then: `git ls-remote`: if it displays your remote branches and HEAD SHA1s, the connection works; you can start pushing your local commits using that new SSH URL.